# How to position the sharing buttons on upper-left corner of the game and not the view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Construct 2 game engine to create a html 5 game and I want to integrate 3rd party sharing option called AddThis. Is working by inserting a script in the html file. 
Everything is showing, but I am having difficulties positioning the sharing buttons on upper-left corned of the game and not on the browser. I tried using the CSS options to position the element but I could not make it work. It is important to keep this sharing element in the Index.html and not the game.html so the sharing link is directed to the index.html and not the game.html.
Here is how the page is looking right now [Preview page](http://synapse1one.com/Test_AddThis_v2/) (the sharing buttons take 5-15 seconds to load)

[image]
Here is the exported [game](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139926126/Forums/scirra/Test_AddThis_v2.zip)

Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Is there any concern not to put your `AddThis` div into your `main` div?

Comment: If I put the AddThis on the main div before the iframe, it will shift the game down, or if I put it after the iframe , the AddThis will not even show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the offset() of your `iframe` and `iframe canvas` then get the total top and left from both. Now you have to apply the top and left to `#addthis` like

```
$(function(){
    function setSocialIconPosistion(c) {
      var o = $('#main iframe').contents().find('#c2canvas').offset(),//get canvas offset
          po = $('#main iframe').offset(),//get iframe offset
          t = o.top + po.top, // get total top of both offset
          l = o.left + po.left;// get total left of both offset
      // now apply it to your social icon container
      $('#addthis').css({
         'top': t + 'px',
         'left': l + 'px'
      });
    }
    // bind on resize of window
    $(window).resize(function () {
      setSocialIconPosistion();
    });
    // call when page loads
    setSocialIconPosistion();
});
```

Add the above code to your `index.html` page.

Comment: Thanks, is definitely working when I resize the browser window, but it does not work when the page loads the first time. If I resize the browser window fast enough the buttons are miss-aligned (like they remain behind). I am thinking that the size_iframe function is executed before the setSocialIconPosition. I also inserted this setTimeout(setSocialIconPosistion, 2000); but has no effect.

Comment: This is because, your social media icons are loading from some other plugin and are not showing on page loads. To resolve the issue you can enter some default text in your `addthis`  container.